# Datagridview add Checkbox on some cell using <DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn>, not a column

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I have a `DataGirdView` that is bound to a List.

I would like to add `CheckBox` on some cell by `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`, but that is no controllers display on my datagridview. Below is my code:

```
class ColumnNames
{
    public string Check { get; set; }
    public string Index { get; set; }
    public string SubIndex { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public ColumnNames(
        string Check,
        string Index,
        string SubIndex,
        string Name,
        string Value
        )
    {
        this.Check = Check;
        this.Index = Index;
        this.SubIndex = SubIndex;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Value = Value;
    }
}

itemsList.Add(new ColumnNames(Check, Index, SubIndex, Name, DataType));
datagridview.DataSource = itemsList;
datagridview.Rows[0].ReadOnly = true;
datagridview.Rows[0].Cells[0] = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
datagridview.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = false;
```

when I run this code, I only get the string 'false' on cell[0].
I had monitor this cell using break point, this cell is "Datagirdviewcheckboxcell" , but no checkbox controller on this.
How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: because you set your column property readonly, try removing `datagridview.Rows[0].ReadOnly = true;` line

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe the checkbox will only operate properly against a boolean property.  Do you have control over the class?  Can you add a property like `public bool CheckBool { get { return bool.Parse(this.Check); } set { this.Check = value.ToString(); } }` and then bind to that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you set in this line `new ColumnNames(Check, Index, SubIndex, Name, DataType)` Check as "string" with value "false".

Change ColumnNames to:

```
 ...
 public bool Check { get; set; }
 ...
   public ColumnNames(bool Check, ...)
   {
        this.Check = Check;
        ...
   }
 ...
```

Then just:

```
        List<ColumnNames> itemsList = new List<ColumnNames>();
        itemsList.Add(new ColumnNames(true,"Index", "SubIndex", "Name", "DataType"));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = itemsList;
```

Results in:

[image]

No need for: `datagridview.Rows[0].Cells[0] = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();`

In case you need different types of cells in one column you will have to go with custom DataGridViewColumn.

According to this answer: [creating a custom column type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933880/creating-a-custom-column-type)
You have available two tutorials:

- http://www.codemag.com/article/0707061
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881.aspx

Then just stick with object type of Check property in your class and in your custom implementation paint cell based on value type.

Something like:

```
switch(Check.GetType()){
      case typeof(Boolean): /* draw CheckBox */ break;
      default: /* draw string */ break; //you can keep string in default with all other types.
}
```

Comment: But when I use this class public bool Check { get; set; }. I will got a column checkbox. But I only like to have one or 2 rows have checkbox, the others not.

Comment: Check out my update. Sorry do not have time to write you here so complex solution like that ;)